# JQuery-Widget : Not working properly

Tags: jquery-widgets

I'm currently studying jquery widget. What I did was convert a working javascript code into jquery widget. 
So the goal would be able to create a chart and update it when new data arrives. In the code that I'm going to show you, I just used timeout to update the data.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/3tu4sp1e/1/)

If you're using chartjs, you'll definitely know that you need to call **destroy** to delete the iframe created by chartjs then **recreate** it to successfully update the data.

I was able to redraw the chart but when you hover it, I could still see the previous chart. I know that that kind of scenario happens only if I didn't destroy it properly. But I have this code which is supposed to destroy the iframe.

```
update: function() {
  this.destroy();
  this._create();
}
```

1) If I'm not deleting the iframe, then what is?

2) how will I correct this code?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with my code is when I used **this** then called destroy. Because when you say **this** I think it is referring to the element created not what new Chart(...) returns. So what I did was save the value returned by new Chart(...) then used that to destroy the chart. see how I did that in the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ht8p6c4u/)

```
options : {
  labels : [],
  data : [],
  pieChart: null
},update: function(){
  pieChart.destroy();
  pieChart._create();
}
```

If you have additional or more meaningful answer than mine, please feel free to post it as well. Thanks :)